# Home page shows recent post, serps rank post within homepage

Tags: search, seo, google-search

When I search for the title of one of my post in Google I see:

```
Site Name- Tag Line
www.mydomain.com
Gibberish gibberish gibberish Hereis the the title of my post
```

I have to go DEEP into the serps to find:

```
Post Title - Site Name
www.mydomain.com/post
description of the post is here
```

What gives? It looks so ugly when someone searches for a keyword and my main site comes up, title has no keywords, and all you see is the keywords in the description wrapped in between a bunch of irrelevant sentences.